# Unexpected token * with tensorflow import

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, import, unexpected-token

I am currently having a problem with importing tensorflow into my project.

I'm trying to make this code work:
https://gist.github.com/learncodeacademy/a96d80a29538c7625652493c2407b6be

However, when I run it with this command:

```
node iris-tensorflow-js.js.js
```

I encounter this error:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import * as tf from "@tensorflow/tfjs/dist/index"
                                                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
```

The strange thing is that the import is well recognized by WebStorm.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code snippet uses ECMAScript module imports (`import` instead of `require()`) which Node.js does not yet allow by default. Here are two things you can try:

## Start Node.js with a flag

```
node --experimental-modules iris-tensorflow-js.js
```

Note that you might have to [rename the file to end in `.mjs`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/esm.html#esm_enabling).

## Use the `esm` module

```
npm install --save esm
node -r esm iris-tensorflow-js
```

Answer (score 0):

Node doesn't support import/export or ES6 modules out of the box.

You need to save the file as `.mjs` instead of `.js` and start with:

```
node  --experimental-modules  index.mjs
```

Also, you can transpile your code to ES5 using `babel` and use it.